# Can people cheat at Onlive Homefront?

Tags: onlive, homefront

I recently purchased and started playing Homefront for Onlive.

I noticed a lot of suspicious things, such as:

- head shots from across the world
- instant perfect aiming
- people with 3x the score of anyone else.

I got worried  if they are using some kind of hack program or cheap code and all my enforces will be in vain. Or if I just need keep practicing more and reach they skill level?

Comment: Wasting your time or a futile effort - Those have the same meaning in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible it is to cheat through OnLive, given that all you receive is the video stream of your play.

Comment: Curious Non-OnLive (should that be NonLive?) user here - does OnLive only let users play multi-player games with other OnLive users then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Homefront on OnLive runs on OnLive's servers people can't get access to the game files, so cheating should be out of the question. But, when Homefront was released it had many errors which people exploited in multiplayer. OnLive has fixed those errors. But there are maybe some little things that people are still exploiting that can't be fixed. I say maybe, because you can't know for sure. What is sure is that cheating is definitely way more dificult, if not imposible on OnLive, than on other systems because people don't have access to the game files.

It is also true that many people have great skils in Homefront on OnLive, as they are playing the game daily.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question if OnLive only let users play multi-player games with other OnLive users then? Yes, multiplayer is only with other OnLive users which is more secure and makes sure that all have great multiplayer latency, as OnLive multiplayer is basically a giant LAN because you play with people who are on the same data center or connected through the internet backbone. So, all can have a great multiplayer experience.

But, OnLive have stated that they can support multiplayer with PC gamers or other platforms. It's up to the game publishers to decide upon this. To date no publisher has opted this way because of the many benefits that OnLive's kind of multiplayer brings.

The publisher of EVE Online has stated that they are talking with OnLive to bring EVE Online to them, so it might happen that OnLive will get an MMO game with support for multiplayer gaming with PC and console gamers.